# regex with special characters in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to preg_replace `charset=blablabla;` and `charset=blablabla"` with `charset=utf-8;`      and `charset=utf-8"`. Please see `;` `=` and `"` characters, and of course searched string can be lower/uppercase.

Can you help me?

Comment: In what context do these snippets appear?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the value with something like:

```
$subject = 'Testing... charset=baz; and charset=bat" :-)';
echo preg_replace('/(?<=charset=)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(?=[;"])/', 'utf-8', $subject);
// Testing... charset=utf-8; and charset=utf-8" :-)
```

Deconstructed, the regex matches:

- A point immediately following `charset=` (using a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))
- A sequence of one or more alphanumeric, underscore or hyphen characters (to be replaced)
- If followed by either a semicolon or double quote character

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
echo preg_replace("#charset=[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\;)?#", "charset=utf-8$1", "charset=sdfsfsds");
```